# How to prevent other website or domain from download our content and display it via CURL on their domain?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Recently we found our websites created on our domain gets automatically copied or mirrored at a different unknown domain website. These unknown websites at unknown domain are updating automatically whenever we update our websites.

https://ourdomain.com mirrored at : https://findacrew.se/index.php/SOCRATES
https://ourdomain.com/printversion/ mirrored at: https://findacrew.se/printversion/
https://ourdomain.com/News mirrored at: https://findacrew.se/News
https://ourdomain.com/Web-mail/ mirrored at: https://findacrew.se/Web-mail

Whenever we create any website on our domain it automatically gets created on this unknown domain.

Our hosting service provider Hostgator says : The issue is that the other site may download your content and display it via CURL.

Please help us by guiding what should we do to break this connection between our domain and this unknown domain.

**Question update: 1:** We have been told by our hosting providers support team that: The domain findacrew.se is pointed to our domains dedicated IP address. For example, if someone type http://findacrew.se/, it redirect to our dedicated IP which is address of our website. Since our domain is hosted on a dedicated IP, the domain findacrew.se will load the content of our site. How to Block other website domain DNS from pointing to our domain's dedicated IP address?

**Question update: 2:** Further update: We found that the domain  has been registered by Eurodns.So we have filed a Complaint against domain findacrew.se to Eurodns with following content:

To

EuroDNS S.A.

Dear Sir,

Greetings

We are the legal owner of domain ourdomain.com with dedicated I.P.... A domain registered at you  has been pointed to our dedicated IP address which is unethical and illegal. For example, if someone type http://findacrew.se/, it redirect to our dedicated IP ourdomain.com with dedicated I.P. ....., which is address of our website. Since our domain ourdomain.com is hosted on a dedicated IP, the domain findacrew.se loads the content of our site. Therefore It is a kind request to please Block this domain  domain DNS from pointing to our domain's dedicated IP address. For your help we would be highly obliged. Please consider this request on a priority basis because we are facing serious issues every day.

**Question Update : 3**
We have discovered that all these domains from a single entity are pointed towards our IP address:findacrew.at  findacrew.be findacrew.ch findacrew.gr findacrew.nl findacrew.ro findacrew.ru findacrew.se  findascrew.com

Comment: This article might help https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/smarter-way-to-prevent-image-hotlinking-with-htaccess/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Hotlink protection is currently “enabled” for all our websites. But this is not solving our problem. The problem is the unknown domain is behaving in the same way our domain behaves. For example whenever we create a new website on our domain, the same website gets created on that unknown domain.

Comment: Does your (legitimate) site leverage certificate-based encryption? I *believe* that would prevent whatever actors who are pointing their domain to your IP from being able to do so without at least a certificate warning

Comment: This is not just about one domain pointing towards our dedicated IP. Following domains are owned by a single entity and they all are pointed towards our I.P. Address:
findacrew.at 
findacrew.be
findacrew.ch
findacrew.gr 
findacrew.nl 
findacrew.ro 
findacrew.ru 
findacrew.se 
findascrew.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions.

Answer (score 1):

> We have been told by our hosting providers support team that: The domain findacrew.se is pointed to our domains dedicated IP address.

The problem can be solved by properly configuring your web server in order to serve your website's pages **only when it is accessed from its URL** `www.socratesjournal.com`

---

What is going on?

The DNS record for the domain `findacrew.se` is misconfigured or outdated and it turns out it points to your server's dedicated IP address.

When someone browses to `findacrew.se`, her/his browser queries the DNS server in order to resolve the domain name.
The DNS server returns your IP address (at the time of writing `216.10.241.94`).
Then the browser connect to that IP address.

What is important to note is how the connection is established: when the browser connects to the resolved IP address the domain name is sent to the server (in the `Host` entry of the request headers):

```
Host: findacrew.se
```

Your website **ignores the `Host` header** and serves your website's contents despite of its value.

You should configure your website to return a `400` error status code `Bad request` (or drop the connection or serve a blank page) if the `Host` header value doesn't match with your website domain name.

If you miss to do that then it's your fault.

Answer (score 0):

All that's happening here is that someone had a domain that previously used the same IP address you're using now, and they haven't updated it since.  There's nothing malicious going on here.

> We found that the domain has been registered by Eurodns.So we have filed a Complaint against domain findacrew.se to Eurodns with following content

This is laughable... there's certainly nothing unethical or illegal going on here.  Your jump to conclusions have lead you astray from the technical problem.

> How to Block other website domain DNS from pointing to our domain's dedicated IP address?

You don't.  You don't own their domain... they do.  You have no control over someone else's domain.  By the way, you also don't own your IP address.

So, what do you do?  It's very simple.  Configure your web server to redirect to your domain with a `301` status code, indicating a permanent redirect.  If it gets a request for a domain not configured, it redirects to the same path at your actual domain.

As for specifically how to do that... you didn't bother telling us what web server you're using so you'll have to Google for it or post a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Why do we complex the issues when the solution is easy?
This is my solution which I found online. It really works fast and solved my problem.

Insert this code in your .htacces

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domainname.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.domainname.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's what almost all of these answers here told you to do.  Glad you figured it out.  Also, please use `example.com` in the future in your questions, if you're looking for a generic name to use.

Comment: Thank you Brad and everyone for the help.